# Hint for Simple Continuous Function and its peculiar property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Claim**:

Let $f:[a,b] \mapsto \Bbb R$ be $continuous$ with $f(a)=f(b)$. Then

there $\exists c,d \in [a,b]$ s.t.  $d-c = {b-a\over 2}$ and $f(c)=f(d)$

---

**Question**:

I want to prove above claim. At first I had tried to find some special occasion
of continuous function

be linear, but it seems to specific compared to the given condition. Any notion or hint that I can

use?

Comment: You can consider the auxiliary function $g(x) := f(x + \frac{b-a}{2}) - f(x)$, defined for $x\in [0, \frac{b-a}{2}]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. As suggested by Rigel, consider the function
$$g(x) := f(x + \frac{b-a}{2}) - f(x)$$
which is continuous in the interval $[a, \frac{b+a}{2}]$. Then, since $f(b)=f(a)$, it follows that
$$g(a)\cdot g(\frac{b+a}{2})=\left(f(\frac{b+a}{2}) - f(a)\right)\left(f(b) - f(\frac{b+a}{2})\right)=-\left(f(\frac{b+a}{2}) - f(a)\right)^2\leq 0.$$
What may we conclude by using the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Comment: how's my continue of your hint ?

Comment: I am the same one who ask ans success your hint.

Comment: @jackerysmith Sorry, my mistake. Your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your gentle help. I don't know what Intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

(Continue with Robert Z's hint)

Then $\exists c \in [a, {b+a \over 2}]$ s.t. $g(c)=0$ since $g$ is $continuous$.

$g(c)=0$ implies $f(c +{b-a\over 2})-f(c) = 0$

which means $f(c) = f(d)$ when $d= c+{b-a\over 2}$